# Every site just turned blue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

Probably not intentional, but every site's theme just turned a(n admittedly nice) shade of blue.

**CGCC:**

> [image: Blue CGCC?]

**Infosec:**

> [image: Blue infosec? Wait it was already blue I think...]

**Cooking:**

> [image: Blue cooking?! What's going on?]]

**Worldbuilding:**

> [image: Blue Worldbuilding?!? This has gone too far!]

Comment: Not intentional! We just now shipped a change using CSS custom properties more widely and seems you caught a bug. We'll have a fix out shortly.

Comment: And dark mode on SO looks awful (very dull). @Dan, Is this caused by the same thing or was that intentional?

Comment: I find this blue color hard to read actually. Best is blackish text on white background.

Comment: @Nasser It's an unintentional change (see Dan Cormier's comment), they'll be changing it back to the way it was before soon ([tag:status-planned]).

Comment: We have a fix building out as we speak. It'll arrive on production soon

Comment: @BenKelly Is this also why the avec-serif fonts have all switched to sans-serif (e.g. on Physics)?

Comment: @rob Yep! I'll post details in the answer once the fix is verified to be in place

Comment: I was planning on upvoting this for the recognition of the change, but I don't agree that it's admittedly nice. It's hard on the eyes, in my opinion.

Comment: @ggorlen It was mostly a joke, it could be much worse colors.

Comment: Glad it turned out to be a bug rather than a feature. It's hard to tell sometimes.

Comment: @ggorlen it is only April, 1st once a year. ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. Short version: There was an upstream change in our [Stacks library](https://stackoverflow.design/) that caused the css specificity of the default theme to be higher than the network themes. As a result, the default theme was applied to all of the components (buttons, fonts, and so on) across the network. We put in a quick (but reliable) fix on the Stack Exchange-side of things while we look into addressing the root cause in Stacks.

Comment: Does the SE test environment have an upstream "test" Stacks file where changes should roll to first, before that file is moved to production? If not, adding that process would help catch bugs like these because you'd notice it right away in the SE test site environment.